# Combine loop variables outputs together with variable inputs into one line

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, grep

```
var1=( some command together )    

echo $var1
myserver user@xx.xx.xx.xx load24 /dev/tty  user1
myserver user@xx.xx.xx.xx load24 /dev/tty  user2
myserver user@xx.xx.xx.xx load24 /dev/tty  user3
myserver user@xx.xx.xx.xx load24 /dev/tty  user4

var2=$( some command together | awk '{print $5}')

echo "$var2"
user1
user2
user3
user4


for i in $var2;
do 
    ldapsearch -xyx $i
done;
```

The output of the loop will be like

```
DEP AB BC CD EF
dep GH IJ KL MN
DEP OP QR ST UV
DEP WX YZ AC BC
```

Now i want to combine all the varibales to look it as

```
myserver user@xx.xx.xx.xx load24 /dev/tty  user1 EP AB BC CD EF
myserver user@xx.xx.xx.xx load24 /dev/tty  user2 dep GH IJ KL MN
myserver user@xx.xx.xx.xx load24 /dev/tty  user3 DEP OP QR ST UV
myserver user@xx.xx.xx.xx load24 /dev/tty  user4 DEP WX YZ AC BC
```

Note - i don't want to redirect any output to any temporary file, just want to generate the last output to write

Comment: If you stick to the idea of using 'some command' in your question, it will be considered that it can not be reproduced and deleted.  I see where you're going but you should correct that and also try to loop through each line of the first command.  That will make your intention more obvious and your code will make much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I've made the example standalone concerning `$var1` and `$var2`:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=$(for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo "a$i b$i  user$i"; done)
echo "$var1"

var2=$(for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo "user$i"; done)
echo "$var2"

for i in $var2
do
  j=$((j+1))
  line=$(echo "$var1" | head -n $j | tail -n 1)
  printf "%s  %s\n" "$line" "$(echo ldap result for $i)"
done
```

This outputs:

```
a1 b1  user1
a2 b2  user2
a3 b3  user3
a4 b4  user4
user1
user2
user3
user4
a1 b1  user1  ldap result for user1
a2 b2  user2  ldap result for user2
a3 b3  user3  ldap result for user3
a4 b4  user4  ldap result for user4
```

In the `printf` line, just replace the `echo ldap result for $i` command by the command you want, such as `ldapsearch -xyx $i`.

Note: with zsh (instead of bash), this could even be a bit simpler due its support of arrays.

An alternative solution based on the `paste` command (though spacing is less controllable):

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=$(for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo "a$i b$i  user$i"; done)
echo "$var1"

var2=$(for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo "user$i"; done)
echo "$var2"

for i in $var2
do
  echo "ldap result for $i"
done | paste <(echo "$var1") -
```

Answer (score 0):

Do everything in a loop:

```
while read -r serv addr load tty usr; do
   printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n" \
      "${serv}" "${addr}" "${load}" "${tty}" "${usr}" $(ldapsearch -xyx "${usr}")
done < <( some command together )
```

With `< <( some command together )` you redirect the output of `some command together` into the while-loop.

Comment: your loop sense logic within it but it seems there is something wrong with the redirection , it's not working at all. syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: Maybe a problem with `some command together` or running /bin/sh? You can try `some command together | while read .... done` instead.